# Вызов С++ функции из ассемблера

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Есть массив в ASM (уже инициализированный), вызывается функция С++ которая сортирует и возвращает уже отсортированный массив. Написал код, но получаю ошибку.

source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}

extern "C" int *SortMass(int* m)
{
    for (int i = sizeof(m) - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (m[j] > m[j + 1])
            {
                int foo = m[j];
                m[j] = m[j + 1];
                m[j + 1] = foo;
            }
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(m);++i)
        cout << m[i] << endl;
    return m;
}
```

ASM

```
.386 ;
.model flat
extern _SortMass : proc

.data
    mas db 12, 2, 7, 3, 2, 1, 21
.code
    mov     ax,@data
    mov     ds,eax

    mov edx, offset mas
    call _SortMass

    push    EBP
    mov     EBP, ESP      

mov eax,[ebp+4]     ; get the address of the array
mov ebp, eax        ; BP now points to the array
mov eax, [ebp]      ; get value of first element
add eax,[ebp+2]     ;   add remaining elements
add eax,[ebp+4]

pop EBP
ret


end
END
```

Вот такую получаю ошибку:

[image: ошибка]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не связано напрямую с тем, что пишет вам ассемблер при компиляции, но все же вот список замечаний к вашему коду:

1. Если вы компилируете под Windows, то вам не нужно инициализировать ds. Если вам таки удастся скомпилировать программу, то она благополучно упадет при попытке перезаписать значение в этом регистре.
2. Вы предполагаете, что C++ функция принимает указатель на начало массива в регистре edx, но я на вашем месте не был бы так уверен. Лучше явно задать соглашение вызова для функции `SortMass` (например, stdcall или fastcall), и в соответствии с этим же соглашением передавать ей параметры.
3. В С++ части не нужна функция main - ваша функция main по факту находится в ассемблерной части.
4. `sizeof` от указателя даст вам размер указателя. Судя по всему, компилируете вы в 32-битный код, поэтому `sizeof(m)` у вас будет равен 4. `sizeof` не определяет магическим способом размер массива, переданного по указателю, он просто определяет размер переданного ему аргумента. Вам нужно вместе с указателем на начало массива также передавать в функцию и его размер, и использовать этот размер вместо `sizeof`.
5. В "сишной" функции вы принимаете указатель на целое число (на начало массива), а в ассемблерной части создаете массив из 7 байт. Определитесь - вам либо нужно создавать массив элементов размера dword, что в вашем случае будет соответствовать массиву int в c++, либо наоборот, в c++ части принимать указатель на массив char (что соответствует массиву байт на ассемблере).
6. Кусок начиная с `push ebp` и заканчивая `pop ebp` как-то совсем не в тему. Просто скопированный и вставленный кусок из какого-то примера, никак не связанный с остальным кодом. Просто удалите его.

### Дополнение по поводу соглашений вызова.

Язык Си поддерживает несколько соглашений вызова: `cdecl`, `stdcall`, `fastcall`, `pascal`. Различаются они способом передачи аргументов (через регистры или стек), порядком передачи через стек (обратный порядок для `stcall` и `cdecl` и прямой для `pascal`), и кто выравнивает стек (вызываемый код или вызывающий код - `stdcall` или `cdecl`). По факту соглашения нужны для того, чтобы вызывающий код клал аргументы именно в то место, откуда его потом заберет вызываемая функция (ну и чтобы стек был правильно выровнен). Все соглашения позволяют менять переданный через параметр указатель - через передачу двойного указателя, но это по факту вам не нужно, т.к. у вас в функции указатель не меняется, а просто происходит сортировка данных по указателю.

В зависимости от используемого компилятора, выбранного уровня оптимизации компилятор может выбрать для функции разные соглашения вызова. Для функции используемой внутри "модуля" это не имеет большого значения, т.к. в этом случае компилятор сам согласует способ передачи параметров. Но для функций, доступных извне нужно явно задавать соглашение, вызывать функцию согласно этому же соглашению.

В вашем коде вы передаете указатель на массив в регистре, но может оказаться, что функция будет искать его в стеке, а найдет там какой-то мусор. Если же вдруг компилятор С++ захочет использовать соглашение fastcall, то первый параметр функция будет искать скорее всего в регистре `ecx`, а не `edx` (скорее всего - потому что соглашение fastcall не стандартизовано, и лучше его использовать для вызовов между модулями, скомпилированными одним и тем же компилятором). Вот как раз для того чтобы гарантировать то, что функция будет искать параметр там где нужно, как раз и нужно явно прописывать соглашения вызова.

Comment: Спасибо,
1. Сделано
2. Данные соглашения не могут модифицировать указатель, а без него прога не хочет работать
3. Я её использовал просто для проверки кода на ошибки
4. Добавил параметр и переменную в asm
5. Исправил на dw
6. удалил

Comment: @nait123321, 2 - во-первых ваша функция не модифицирует указатель, а меняет данные по указателю - сортирует их, это две совершенно разные вещи; во-вторых можно возвращать измененное значение указателя через `return`; в-третьих изменять указатель можно передавая двойной указатель (соответственно, тип аргумента должен быть `int **`); в-четвертых в любом случае, если не указать явно соглашение вызова, то компилятор по своему "желанию" выберет одно из трех - cdecl, stdcall, fastcall, большого выбора у него тут нет. 5 - нужно `dd` ("define dword")